# SQL Server - How to get last numeric value in the given string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get last numeric part in the given string.

For Example, below are the given strings and the result should be last numeric part only

- SB124197       -->  124197
- 287276ACBX92   -->  92
- R009321743-16  -->   16

How to achieve this functionality. Please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48302981/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see **[ask]**.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
select right(@str, patindex('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@str)) - 1)
```

**Explanation:**

Using [**PATINDEX**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) with `'%[^0-9]%'` as a search pattern you get the starting position of the *first* occurrence of a character that is *not* a number.

Using `REVERSE` you get the position of the first non numeric character starting from the back of the string.

**Edit:**

To handle the case of strings not containing non numeric characters you can use:

```
select case 
          when patindex(@str, '%[^0-9]%') = 0 then @str
          else right(@str, patindex('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@str)) - 1)
       end
```

If your data *always* contains at least one non-numeric character then you can use the first query, otherwise use the second one.

**Actual query:**

So, if your table is something like this:

```
mycol
--------------
SB124197
287276ACBX92
R009321743-16
123456
```

then you can use the following query (works in SQL Server 2012+):

```
select iif(x.i = 0, mycol, right(mycol, x.i - 1))
from mytable
cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9]%', reverse(mycol) )) as x(i)
```

**Output:**

```
mynum
------
124197
92
16
123456
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a51ab/3)

Comment: Will fail when there is no non numeric value in the string

Comment: Wrong again.. It will throw invalid length passed to right function error..

Comment: Check this `declare @str varchar(10)= '92'
select right(@str, patindex('%[^0-9]%',reverse(@str)) - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `Patindex`

```
SELECT RIGHT(strg, COALESCE(NULLIF(Patindex('%[^0-9]%', Reverse(strg)), 0) - 1, Len(strg)))
FROM   (VALUES ('SB124197'),
               ('287276ACBX92'),
               ('R009321743-16')) tc (strg)
```

After reversing the string, we are finding the position of first non numeric character and extracting the data from that position till the end..

**Result :**

```
-----
124197
92
16
```